# Polar integration

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I want to calculate the area of the region R between the curves

$$r = 3\sin(\theta)$$
$$r = 1 + \sin(\theta)$$

You can see the imge below, for a clear visual. I am stuck. I only got to find where the curves do intersect in terms of angles, which is when $3\sin(\theta) = 1 + \sin(\theta)$ that is $\theta = \pi/6$ and $\theta = 5\pi/6$.

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The cardioid lies above the circle for $0\le \theta\le {\pi/6}$ and $5\pi/6\le \theta \le \pi.$ These regions have the same area, due to the symmetry $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin\theta.$ Hence it suffices to calculate two times the area for $0\le \theta\le {\pi/6},$ i.e. $$\int_0^{\pi/6} [(1+\sin\theta)^2-9\sin^2\theta]\,d\theta$$

Answer (score 1):

The method I present is slow, but effective. First of all, your circle has polar equation $r = 3\sin(\theta)$ which means its diameter measures $3$.
Hence the area of that circle is $\frac{9}{4}\pi$, by simple geometry.

Now, if we find the area OUTSIDE the cardioid (the curve with polar equation $r = 1+\sin(\theta)$) and substract it from the total area of the circle, we will get the area of the region $R$ you want.

Let's call $A$ the area of the region outside the cardioid, but inside the circle (it's the half moon shape region, white coloured above).

$$A = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\left(3\sin(\theta)\right)^2\ \text{d}\theta - \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/6}^{5\pi/6}\left(1 + \sin(\theta)\right)^2\ \text{d}\theta$$

The integration is really easy, and you will get

$$A = \pi$$

Thence,

$$R = \text{Area Circle} - A$$

$$R = \dfrac{9}{4}\pi - \pi$$

$$R = \dfrac{5}{4}\pi$$